Duplicate getCasts functionality inside the Laravel core
Environment - Laravel 8, PHP 7.4
I am faced with such a problem. It takes a very long time to work out the code. Here is an example of a request:
public function index()
    {
        XHprof::startProfiling();

        $companyRounds = CompanyRounds::all();

        $res = $companyRounds->map(function ($companyRound) {
            return $companyRound;
        });

        return Response::success('', $res, 200);
    }

Here is CompanyRounds model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CompanyRounds extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'company_rounds';

    protected $appends = [
        'parsed_date',
    ];


    protected function getParsedDateAttribute() {
        return Helpers::dateFormatter($this->date ?? '');
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'round',
        'date',
        'quarter',
        'investors',
        'pre_money',
        'post_money',
        'sum',
        'stock_price',
        'investment',
        'dept',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
        'date' => 'datetime',
        'stock_price' => 'float',
        'investment' => 'boolean',
        'dept' => 'boolean',
    ];
}

Next, I decided to check the request in XHProf. And I saw this picture:

In database I have 363 records. And I have a feeling that every time I get a record, Laravel checks casts for existence and so on.
How can this be avoided?
Because of this problem, the speed of the code slows down tenfold.
I would not like to completely abandon casts and appends, because there is a lot of logic tied to them
I tried to delete all castes and append, but still Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::getCasts() is called 5904 times
Here XHprof Debug with model without casts and appends


Your issue is more related to the fact that you are getting 300+ entries from the database than the core code of laravel. You could use some pagination to avoid that

@N69S Is 300 entries a lot? I have an information portal and there is a need for this. The point is that instead of checking casts once for a model, Laravel checks them every time it receives a record

If you are talking about "CastAttribute()" being called 3260+ times, it's because you have 9 attributes per 363 entries to be casted. so its called only once per attribute. About the pagination, Having 300 entries is nothing, showing 300 entries is a lot. that is why we use pagination and filters. In the end, your user will interact with 10 at most if not only one.

Just for the sake of testing, ca you show a diagram when public $incrementing = false;?

@N69S Its only just example. If another example is needed, I have graphs that require a huge amount of data to build and send it to front API. And anyway i must get many entries. I cant understand why laravel called CastAttribute() for each entry, but not for 1 model. And why 9 attributes, i didnt understand this point?

@N69S Sure! https://imgur.com/a/RavrKEY

yeah, avoiding an array_merge() improved performance. You have three options now, either elevate an issue on laravel github repository, implement pagination or avoid using model (using DB::class) and not use model attribute casting.

for the 9 attributes, you have 6 plus 2 timestamps (since $timestamps = true - redundant) and the primary key.

@N69S But created_at and updated_at included in casts. Anyway ill try redis cache my queries
